# How to remove only a string from a column of a data frame

Tags: python

I have such following values in a column in a data frame. And I wrote like the following code to remove only 'carflowNormal_' part in the column. But after running the code, I see the code worked correctly but it also removes all the rows that are related to '5001'. In the '@id' column, there are values like 5001, 5002, 5003 and ... but I see that are all removed after running the code. I appreciate if any one suggest me a solution to only remove carflowNormal_ from those cells that has this string.

```
subset_df['@id'] = subset_df['@id'].str.replace('carflowNormal_', '', regex=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ3E6.png)

Here is what I have tried!

```
subset_df['@id'] = subset_df['@id'].str.replace('carflowNormal_', '', regex=True)

subset_df['@id'] = subset_df['@id'].str.replace(r'carflowNormal_(?=\d)', '', regex=True)

subset_df['@id'] = subset_df['@id'].str.replace(r'^carflowNormal_', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are expecting as an output. That first line of code you provided does exactly what you want it to do. It removes `'carflowNormal_'` from the cells, leaving only the `0.0'`, `'1.0'`, and `'5001'` as the values.

Comment: unless youre doing some filtering prior to running that line, where subset_df is the rows only with `'carflowNormal_'`?? But you need to share more info, details, and code. And don't post it in pictures